# How to access wallet if password is lost

Tags: parity-wallet

Hi I have deposited a bit of ether in Parity. I must have copied wrongly the password. Any other ways to access my Ether. I appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Parity wallets seem to be in the same format as geth which leads me to believe they will be in the same directory.

I would suggest to back up your keys to avoid this problem in the future [backup parity keys](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Backing-up-&-Restoring)

**From that above link one can find their keys in the following directory.**

**On Mac:**

```
 $HOME/Library/Application Support/io.parity.ethereum/keys
```

**On Linux:**

```
$HOME/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/keys
```

**On Windows:**

```
%HOMEPATH%/AppData/Roaming/Parity/Ethereum/keys.
```

Lastly, if that doesn't work maybe this [wallet recovery service should be able to help you](https://walletrecoveryservices.com/)

Comment: Seems to be missing the important information about how the **passwords need to be backed up** because the key files are encrypted.